# Java Hashtable set all keys with same value

Tags: java, collections, maps, hashtable, multimap

I am currently working in java and using a hashtable with keys and values.

What I want to do is walk through a file and put every word as a key into the hashtable, with a certain probability that should be initialized as 1/total individual words.

Currently my code loops trhough the file and for every word does: `map.put(word,0)`. (value is initlaized as 0 because I don't know the total number of words yet since it's still looping).
At the end of this loop i'd like to make every value in the hashtable 1/map.size(), is there an easy way to do this instead of having to interate through all hashtable keys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your best bet IMHO: Iterate through the keys.

Comment: Why would you want to intiialize each value to 1/(total words) ? Should a word that appears 100 times have the same probability as a word that appears one time?

Comment: By word i actually mean a combination of two words in different languages("w1 w2"). Their probability should all be initialized equally because I am implementing an algorithm that trains itself in finding the right probabilities of w1 translationg into w2 and the probabilities are thus updated during every trainings loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) if you are using Java 8+:

```
map.replaceAll((k, v) -> 1.0 / map.size());
```